# Passing an attribute to input type in Jeditable

Tags: jquery, jeditable

I'm using Jeditable to edit and post changes to different elements of a page. I'd like to be able to specify whether the edit type should be `text` or `textarea` by looking at an attribute in  I'm editing, `data-type_edit="textarea` for example.

However, passing I don't seem to be able to pass any value or attribute to the 2nd part of the jeditable function where you specify type. Why isn't `type : $(this).attr('data-edit_type')` working in this code:

```
$('.editable.edit-section').editable(function(value, settings) {
    var dbId = $(this).attr("data-db_id");
    var dbTable = $(this).attr("data-db_table");
    var dbCol = $(this).attr("data-db_col");
    submitEdit(value, dbId, dbTable, dbCol);
    // Needed so that value is correctedly displayed with jeditable on page
    return(value);
 }, {
    type : $(this).attr('data-edit_type'),
    submit : "OK",
    cancel : "Cancel",
    tooltip : "Click to edit...",
    onblur : "ignore"
});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try doing.

```
$(this).data('edit_type');
```

I believe this is the correct way to access data attributes through jQuery

Comment: Hmm, while I can see this in the console, it still doesn't work for passing to the type parameter in jeditable.